# how to send parameter from angular ts front to nodejs backend

Tags: node.js, angular

i have a problem with send parameter from .ts to node
my .ts is below:

```
      const idno=row_obj.id;
      console.log("idno is :" + idno);
      const params = new HttpParams().set('params', idno);
      this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/delete_rec",{params}).subscribe(
           () => {}
      );
```

in nodejs file my code is :

```
app.post("/delete_rec",(req,res)=>{

console.log('id number is :' + req.query.params);

});
```

in runtime idno in .ts is correct and displayed on the console,but in nodejs side value of req.query.params  is undefined

Comment: You should try using the `fetch` API for browsers ([`node-fetch`](https://npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) for node). It's really easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

req.params

```
app.post("/delete_rec/:test",(req,res)=>{

console.log('id number is :' + req.params['test]);

});
```

### [more info about params in node here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/express-js-req-params-property/)

req.query

```
this.http.get("http://localhost/angular/ngPost_api/deletePost_api.php", {params:{test}})
```

```
app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.query.test);
  res.send();
});
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@armno/creating-a-url-with-httpparams-in-angular-42783205f3f4